Force git push to ask for user and password / token when git remote URL already contains http://user:password
When I cloned my project, I cloned it with
git clone https://my_user:my_token@github.com/path_to_my_repo

Now, the token included in the URL is a read only token, however, I have the write access token elsewhere available, that I could use to do a git push.
The only issue now is, that git push won't work since it says
remote: Write access to repository not granted.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/path_to_my_repo/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Is there an easy way to just leave everything as is, no changes in the remote URL, and, via some flags or parameter to git push, so that I can enter a user and a token (that has write access)?

Which operating system, which client, and why don't you want to modify the remote URL?

@JimRedmond using Ubuntu linux, git is the client ( https://git-scm.com/ ) and, I do not want to change the remote URL, because that's how it is supposed to be set up, so no one can change it (read-only access); however, there are people, who have the write access :)

This question is similar to: Will remote URL for fetch and push be different?. The accepted answer there should be a workable solution.

@JimRedmond thank you for your find. Yes, this is a solution, however, I would emphasize that, I am cloning the repo with a user and token and that should be the default. I was dreaming of somehow force git push with some kind of flag like -askauth which will allow the push to happen with a different user and token, to the same repo. I believe, this might not be possible at the moment?

Via parameters, you can try git -c url."https://github".pushinsteadof="https://my_user:my_token@github" push. In case you have a credential helper enabled, -c credential.helper= is also needed. my_user and my_token can be literal strings or variables like $my_user where my_user=some_literal_username. Still, this is not an easy way.

@ElpieKay True, it is not an easy solution, still, it is a good suggestion :) Thank you!

A less desirable solution that I found is to edit the .git/config file and comment out the url under the '[remote "origin"]' with a '#', then, duplicate it and modify it to have the desired USER and TOKEN.
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
#   url = https://user1:read_only_token@github.com/user/repository.git
    url = https://user2:read_write_token@github.com/user/repository.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master

This way, it is possible to do a git push for example then go back and comment out the url that was added and uncomment the original one.
I am still looking for a more hassle free solution though, as this would leave both tokens in the .git/config file, which is undesirable.
